# The best ML algorithm to give recommendations to fill in a selection

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, recommender-system

I have a ML problem where I want to suggest a combination of options to the user based on their current choice of options. The options are all boolean (selected or not selected), there are several hundred of them and I have a dataset of user choices. I'm wondering if there is an existing solution for this kind of problem. The suggestions should be based on the current pick not on the users history because the users don't pick options according to what they "like" so much as what they're currently trying to do.

My current thinking is to use K-means to calculate k cluster centers (where k is determined semi-manually using one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) methods), then classify the current user input into one of these clusters taking into account only the picked options (this is the first issue I see with this solution, more on that later) and give them a recommendation by "rounding" the cluster center vector to ones and zeroes to figure out what should be selected.

The first issue I was talking about is that this is a pretty weak prediction as the user has only selected a small subset of all the possible options and I have no way of differentiating the options the user intentionally skipped vs the ones they didn't get around to selecting yet so I can only calculate the error based on the options that are selected by the user but aren't predicted by the cluster.

My second issue is the large number of features, I'm doing some feature selection to fix that.

My third issue is that I'm not completely sure this even makes sense. Intuitively, it seems like the clusters I get via this method should represent the most common sets of choices people make and that I should be able to then extrapolate the appropriate cluster based on an incomplete input but I'm not 100% this will work.

I apologize if this question is too vague, I'm new to ML so I'm not sure where to look for a better approach. Any suggestion as to which algorithms/solutions to research to achieve a suggestion system like this would be appreciated.

EDIT: To give more clarification, the way I see it I have two issues. Properly defining the clusters for the problem and then classifying an incomplete input into one of those clusters. I'm using K-means for the first problem and I'm currently researching a better solution the second issue.

Comment: You can look at collaborative filtering or content-based recommendations. Start off with some theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering and afterwards some code like https://github.com/microsoft/recommenders

Comment: I am familiar with both of these but they aren't suitable for my use case.

Specifically, classical recommender systems assume users have an innate preference for certain types of content and give suggestions in accordance with that preference so the suggestions are based on the users history and the category of the item being recommended. Like I said, that isn't appropriate for my situation, the suggestions need to be based on the current selection, in effect predicting what the user is currently trying to do.

As for collaborative filtering, it has pretty much the same problem.